# Question about why $f$ being compatible need to be shown about equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $:\to $ and $$ is an equivalence relation on $.$
We will say that $$ is compatible with $$ if $\forall \in \forall \in (\to ()=()).$

$(a)$ Suppose $$ is compatible with $.$  Prove that there is a unique function $ℎ:/\to $ such that for all $\in ,ℎ([]_)=().$

$(b)$ Suppose $ℎ:/\to $ and for all $\in ,ℎ([]_)=().$
Prove that $$ is compatible with $.$

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I am able to solve the problem, but there is something I am confused about for part (b).  The hypothesis of the question assumes the map $f$ and that $f$ is compatible.  For (a), $f$ being compatible is used to show that $h$ is well defined.  But for (b), if either it is assume either the maps $h$ and $[x]_R$ or $h$ and $x\mapsto [x]_R,$ then why do I need to show that $f$ is compatible since, the map $h$ is assumed to be well defined, and that requires assumption that $f$ is compatible, otherwise, $h$ would not be well defined by assumption.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only things that are supposed for *both* questions are that $f:A\to B$ is a function and $R$ is an equivalence on $A$. In $(a)$ we also assume $f$ is compatible with $R$ but that is **not** an assumption made in question $(b)$. Since it is not given to us, it must be proven.

> Otherwise, $h$ would not be well defined by assumption.

This is not quite right, at least, not in the spirit of the question. You're *given* a function $h:A/R\to B$, so it is implicit that $h$ is well-defined. It is true that $h([x]_R)=f(x)$ always being true + $h$ being well-defined implies $f$ is compatible, and it is true that if $f$ is not compatible then the *definition* $h([x]_R):=f(x)$ is not well-defined. But you're not asked to define $h$, you're just told it exists.

The realisation that this equation makes sense only if $f$ is compatible is a good realisation; in noticing this, you've basically already solved the exercise.